# Haskell code prints out a list for ints but not for chars

Tags: haskell

My code currently looks like this. It is supposed to show the possible first symbols in the regular expression definition given to us beforehand. I am supposed to print these out as a list. For example, if the answer is supposed to be [1,2], it will come out [1,2] but when the answer is supposed to be ['1','2'] it will come out "12" or when it is supposed to be ['a', 'b'] it will come out "ab". What am I doing wrong?

```
data RE a         -- regular expressions over an alphabet defined by 'a'
    = Empty          -- empty regular expression
    | Sym a          -- match the given symbol
    | RE a :+: RE a  -- concatenation of two regular expressions
    | RE a :|: RE a  -- choice between two regular expressions
    | Rep (RE a)     -- zero or more repetitions of a regular expression
    | Rep1 (RE a)    -- one or more repetitions of a regular expression
    deriving (Show)

firstMatches :: RE a -> [a]
firstMatches Empty = []
firstMatches (Sym a)= a:list
firstMatches(Rep(a))=firstMatches a
firstMatches(Rep1(a))=firstMatches a
firstMatches (Empty :+: b)= firstMatches b
firstMatches (a :+: _) = firstMatches a
firstMatches (a :|: b)= firstMatches a ++ firstMatches b
```

Comment: Are you supposed to print it in a list format, or just return a list? What are the requirements specifically?

Comment: That's what's the `Show` instance for lists does. If you want some other behavior, don't use `show`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong.

`String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`, so if you try to print a `[Char]` it will print as a `String`. This is somewhat of a special case, and it can be a little weird.

`Show` is the typeclass used to print things as a string. The definition of `Show` is something like this:

```
class Show a where
    showsPrec :: Int -> a -> ShowS
    show      :: a -> String
    showList  :: [a] -> ShowS
```

The `showList` function is optional. The [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Show.html#v:showList) states:

> The method `showList` is provided to allow the programmer to give a specialised way of showing lists of values. For example, this is used by the predefined `Show` instance of the `Char` type, where values of type `String` should be shown in double quotes, rather than between square brackets.

So if you define a new type and instantiate `Show`, you can optionally define a special way to `show` a list of your type, separate from the way it's normally shown and separate from the way lists are normally shown. `Char` takes advantage of this, in that a `[Char]` (or equivalently, a `String`), is shown with double-quotes instead of as a list of `Char` values.

---

I can't think of a way to get it to use the default `show` for a `[Char]`. I don't think there is one. A workaround might be to create a `newtype` wrapping `Char` with its own `Show` that uses the default `showList` implementation, but that doesn't seem appropriate here.

If this is homework, I'd expect the grader to know about this already, and I seriously doubt you'd get marked down for it, especially since the problem doesn't appear to be about `show` at all.

Comment: okay. so it turns out the teacher doesn't care if it shows up as a string because as you said, a string is just a list of chars

Comment: @AdityaSirohi: Just for your own reference, the `newtype` solution DarthFennec mentions is: `newtype C = C Char; instance Show C where { show (C c) = show c }`. Then `show (map C "abc")` will produce the string `"['a', 'b', 'c']"` as expected. This is also a good opportunity to use `Data.Coerce.coerce`, which converts safely between a type and a `newtype` wrapper, with no runtime cost, e.g. `coerce "abc" :: [C]`.

Comment: Slight quibble: `show` doesn't *print* anything; it *returns* a string.

Comment: @chepner, `show` doesn't "return" anything, it *evaluates to* a string. >:)

Comment: That's an even bigger quibble than my original quibble :)

Comment: @chepner It still "prints" *to* a string. Printing to a new string and printing to an existing file stream both require the same serialization steps, so I would argue that's a perfectly valid use of the word as long as that distinction is made.